# Deleting letters in a string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I've been assigned to construct a code, doing the following:
Ask the user to input a word (30 letters max), and then delete all the "A,a,O,o" letters and print it without any spaces. eg: input: OkleaAo, output: kle

I've been told the easier way is to use 2 arrays, and with an IF loop, to add letters which aren't A/a/o/O to the second array, and then print it.

I'm really stuck now, I know I have to use pointers, but for it isn't working. 
Any help, advise?

I wrote something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char input[30], *p;
char output[30];

main()
{
    printf("Enter a string:\n", input);
    scanf("%s", input);
    if *(p==o);
    {
        *p=0;
        printf("String after deletion:", input);
    }

}
```

Comment: you mean "pointers" or "points" ?

Comment: I edited it. Sorry im really tired, I'm afraid my curriculum isn't good enough, I'm missing something here. 
It has no good example of how to use pointers or replace a char or print something without spaces. I'm in the dark here. (and online the most relevant thing i can find it's in C++)

Comment: Nothing is subjected to substantial processing.

Comment: 2 things, the arrays aren't in the correct size, they must be 31 characters because c strings are null terminated (one char more required)... second, I think you misunderstood the suggestion that was probably an if INSIDE a loop (using while for example).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char input[30+1];
    char output[30+1];
    int i, j;

    printf("Enter a string :");
    scanf("%30[^\n]", input);

    for(j = i = 0;input[i];++i){
        char *p, ch = input[i];
        p = strchr("AaOo ", ch);
        if(p == NULL)
            output[j++] = ch;
    }
    output[j] = '\0';
    printf("\nString after deletion: %s\n", output);
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char input[30+1];
    char *in, *out;

    printf("Enter a string :");
    scanf("%30[^\n]", input);

    out = in = input;
    while(*in){
        char ch = *in;
        if(ch != 'A' && ch != 'a' && ch != 'O' && ch != 'o' && ch != ' ')
            *out++ = *in;
        ++in;
    }
    *out = '\0';
    printf("\nString after deletion: %s\n", input);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: WOW thanks!
Do you mind explaining me what
p = strchr("AaOo ", ch);
if(p == NULL)
output[j++] = ch;
does? 
I didn't even knew a library called "string.h"

Comment: `strchr` is return a pointer to the specified character string. That is, the transfer if it is not found.